# What should the joiner table include when joining two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am working on a database which as a user table and a party table. A user can go to many parties and the party can host many users. So this is a many-to-many relationship. But since its not possible to have a many to many relationship between two tables, I created a joiner table called 'user_party' table. Now I am not sure what goes in the party table and what goes in the user_party table. For example, user table has basic columns like user_id, user_name, user_email, etc. and party table has information like party_description, party_time, party_location, etc. Should these party table values go to user_party table instead? What values should the joiner table include and what goes in the party table?

Comment: Your Joiner table `user_party` should have an id of each table such as `user_id` for users and `party_id` for party Which will make it easier for you to join these entities

Comment: Like all tables the only thing that should be in them, is the elements unique to both (like above). So additional things you would include in `user_party` table if there was a requirement, would be things like `food_gifted`, `behaved_well`, `arrived_on_time`, i.e. the things related to the user and party.

Comment: @craftdeer Please check my answer and let me know if it does not serve your purpose. Best wishes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The joiner table should be here to maintain the relation between a particular user and a specific party, and in your case, not more.

Before all, the party should be uniquely defined with a `party_id` primary column. Then, a `user_party` table could be define with only two columns: a `user_id` and a `party_id`.

So, the join would involve 3 table rows uniquely identified:

- One from the `user` table (identified by the `user_id` and storing all users details such as `first_name`, `address`...)
- One from the `party` table (identified by the `party_id` and storing all the related info like `location`, `start_datetime`...)
- One from the `user_party`(identified by the t-uple [ `user_id`, `party_id`])

The `user_party` table could only embed some data which are meaningful for single occurrences of the [ `user_id`, `party_id`] t-uple itself, such as the number of beer cans brought to a particular party :)

Eventually, these data could be externally stored into a specific table in order to keep only the relational aspect there and the t-uple extended with another key.

According to the underlying DB engine, the definition may go one step further, with the `user_id` and `party_id` columns of the `user_party` table declared as foreign keys, and additional drop and update triggers to handle automatic data binding across related tables.

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a solution for you. As I understand from your description you need to change your schema a  little bit, and your table should be look like below.
**User(user_id, user_name, user_email);**
**party (party_id,party_description, party_time, party_location);**
**user_party (id,party_id,user_id);**
**hostuser_party (id,party_id,user_id);**

[image]

**Note: hostuser_party table is required if a party hosted by multiple users. If party always hosted by one user then you can add host_id(User_id) column in party table.**

Comment: No need for `user_party` or `hostuser_party` to have its own id. In both cases `(party_id,user_id)` serves well enough for a composite primary key.